# Resolving "'hi' is not recognized as internal or external command..." error using C++ with codeblocks on Windows Vista?

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I am learning C++ in school now. Currently using C++ with codeblocks on my windows vista laptop. I noticed whenever I try to use functions from imported classes from the Clibrary I get an error in the console.

" 'hi' is not recgonized as internal or external command, operable command or batch file "

My code looks like this ...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>  

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    system("hi");
    return 0;
}
```

Just something simple you can see, however I am getting that error. I can use the iostream fine, I have tested the io include and that works... is there something else I need to install to be able to use the cstdlib?

Thank you,
Zach Smith

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is exactly what it looks like: you're trying to execute with `system` a command that simply does not exist, so you'll get just the same error if you typed `hi` at a command prompt (codeblocks has nothing to do with it).  Try using e.g. `system("echo hi")` or any other command that **does** exist and your results might be better.

Comment: That does work! Thank You!

I am curious because the code I gave you is exactly what I copied out of my text when "playing around" (The book is Bruce Eckle's thinking in C++, for the curious). Interesting.

Anyway, Thank You!

Comment: The example you're referencing is in chapter 2, yes? Notice that that sample is under the heading "**Calling other programs**"

Answer (score 6):

system() in cstdlib runs another command on the system.  Unless there's a hi.exe on your path, this is going to fail.  It looks as if you want to write "hi" to stdout, in which case your code should be:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   cout << "hi" << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use iostream, try:

```
cout << "hi" << endl;
```